# Overwriting of records between datatables of two differerent portlets

Tags: jsp, datatable, primefaces

I use Primefaces and JSP, inside my page there are 2 indipendent portlets, one positioned over the other, and each having a datatable. The number of columns is different for each table (3 for the first and 10 for the second)

When the page loads, one or more records from the upper table goes down to the below table, thus hiding and overwriting records belonging to the latter. This happens randomly, not at every page load.

Datables' IDs are different.

Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After a deep code debugging, I found that, when creating datatable, Yahoo's UI "yui-rec" elements were not created and processed progressively, i.e. yui-rec0, yui-rec1, ..., yui-recN from the first table, yui-rec(N+1), .... yui-rec(N+M) from the second table. Instead, some of the first N elements were already found as existing and then moved to the second table.

The issue was solved by redifining the yui-rec ID's, inside each portlet's JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
updateID = function() {
    var table1 = document.getElementById('view<portlet:namespace/>:table1')

    Array.from(table1.getElementsByTagName('tr')).forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.id.includes('yui-rec')) {
         item.id=item.id+'_'
    }})
}

<script>
```